# Upgrading php, mysql, and apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, update

I have been looking around and have not found a good answer to my question. I currently have php 5.3.3 installed via yum on my centos 6.3 server. I need to upgrade to php 5.3.10 or later. It is my understanding that you need to find the correct mysql and apache packages that fit with the php install. Can someone please point me in the direction of a an update guide? Btw I am not looking for "yum update httpd php5" this gets me the old 5.3.3 version. Thanks, Kevin.

Comment: There is no php5.10 yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either [compile from source](http://www.php.net/git.php) (I recommend [creating your own RPM packages](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) and installing those.  It's not that difficult and it sure does make upgrading and uninstalling much easier.) or use someone else's repository.

The [IUS community repo (created and managed by RackSpace) currently has PHP 5.3.16 available](http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/x86_64/repoview/php53u.html).  To use the IUS repository, you need to download two .rpm files and install them manually.  [Instructions start here](http://iuscommunity.org/pages/GettingStarted.html#subscribing-to-the-ius-yum-repository).  You can also find the IUS repository linked from the [official PHP downloads page](http://www.php.net/downloads.php).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want php5.3.10 not php5.10.

On CentOS 6.3, there are no newer php5 versions available. You would have to compile the whole things by hand.

But to get php5.10 compiled, you will have to make sure that all dependencies are installed  in the correct version. And i don't think that they are in the repository.

Maybe you should choose a different distribution.

Comment: Thomas is right, even-though I dont see a reason to upgrade to 5.3.10 while it is not supported by your distro yet.